# How do I specify JSONP as the dataType in an angular $http service request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, angularjs

I'm familiar with using jQuery's `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: //twitter endpoint,
  method:"GET",
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success:function() {
    //stuff
  }
});
```

How can I specify the `JSONP` datatype to an angular `$http` service request?

so far I've tried this:

```
$http.get({
  url: //twitter endpoint,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(){
    //stuff
  }
});
```

It hasnt worked though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can always use `$http.jsonp(url).success(function() {} );`

[$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_jsonp)

Comment: This is nice, but is there a way to specify the data type programmatically?

Comment: Ehh don't think so. I was getting the origin error like you were (different site) -- and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: '/someUrl?cb=JSON_CALLBACK'

}).then(function (response) {
  // stuff
});
```

Comment: `jsonp` is a data type, not an HTTP method.

Comment: @DannyBullis checkout one use case of `method: JSONP` via test spec here: [httpSpec.js#L603](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.3/test/ng/httpSpec.js#L603)

Comment: Voted up. I'm assuming you recieved your downvote from @DannyBullis Your link proves his statement incorrect.